# angular mat-auto-complete validate on the very last user input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Building custom validation to auto-completion in a template-driven form.

**The issue**: the validator function is called with the previous user input value.

**HTML**

```html
<mat-form-field *ngIf="configObj(controls)['type']=== 'employees'">
  <input matInput #employeesf [matTooltip]="configObj(controls)['tooltip']||controls" placeholder="{{controls}}"
    formControlName="{{controls}}"
    [required]="configObj(controls)['require']==='yes'|| configObj(controls)['require']==true "
    (ngModelChange)="_filterEmployees(employeesf.value)" [matAutocomplete]="employeeInput"
    placeholder="{{'translate.select_employee' | translate}}" required appHasSelectedOptionValidator
    [options]="filteredClients" [userInput]="[clientf.value]" />
  <mat-autocomplete panelWidth="auto" #employeeInput="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="employeeClick($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let employee of filteredEmployees" [value]="employee">
      {{employee}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-hint *ngIf="configObj(controls)['display_old_answer']">{{hints[controls]}}</mat-hint>
  <mat-hint *ngIf="!configObj(controls)['display_old_answer'] && configObj(controls)['hint']">
    {{configObj(controls)['hint']}}
  </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS (hasSelectedOptionValidator.ts)**

```js
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, Validator } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHasSelectedOptionValidator]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: HasSelectedOptionValidatorDirective, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class HasSelectedOptionValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  @Input("options") options: string[]
  @Input("userInput") userInput: any

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    console.log('options ', this.options)
    console.log('input ', this.userInput)
    let subby = [];
    this.options.forEach(element => subby.push(element[0]));

    console.log('sub: ', subby);

    if (subby.includes(this.userInput[0])) {
      console.log('in');
      return null;
    } else {

      console.log('not in')

      console.log('subby ', subby)
      console.log('input ', this.userInput[0])

      return { 'selected': false };
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to update validation check upon the very last user input?
and especially the user's selection of one from the auto completion menu.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a c.value which updates immediately

**TS**

```
import { Validator, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'
import {Directive, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHasSelectedOptionValidator]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: HasSelectedOptionValidatorDirective, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class HasSelectedOptionValidatorDirective implements Validator, OnChanges {

  @Input() options :string[]
  @Input() userInput: any;

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    console.log('input is ', c.value)
    console.log('options ', this.options)

    let subby = [];
    this.options.forEach(element => subby.push(element[0]));

    console.log('sub: ', subby);

    if (subby.includes(c.value)) {
      console.log('in');
      return null;
    } else {

      console.log('not in')

    console.log('subby ', subby)
    console.log('input ', c.value)

      return {'selected': false};
    }
  }
}
```